# Question about Poisson process and arrival times

Tags: probability, expectation, poisson-distribution, independence

Problem: On any given day you receive mail in mailbox with probability $p$. Assume whether mail is put in the mailbox or not is independent each day.

1. If the neighbor receive mail in his mailbox with prob $w$, independent each day, what is the probability the first mail (between you and neighbor) arrives after a week?
2. Suppose your mail gets moldy with prob. $q$ when sitting in the mailbox independently of whether mail is actually received in the mailbox. What is the prob. the 1st received moldy mail will come within a week? What is the expected number of days you wait until you receive your 2nd moldy mail?

Attempt: for (1), so far I have
$$
\mathbb{P}[\min\{\text{me get 1st mail, neighbor get 1st mail\} after a week}]
   = \mathbb{P}[\text{I don't receive any mail in 1st week}] \times
     \mathbb{P}[\text{neighbor doesn't receive any mail in 1st week}],
$$
so my answer is $(1-p)^7(1-w)^7$, am I right?

(2) I am thinking
$$
\mathbb{P}[\text{1st received moldy mail will come within a week}] = q^7,
$$
not sure about the second part

Comment: Note: not a Poisson process.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not a Poisson Process.

Let $X$ count the day you first get mail.  Let $Y$ count the day your neighbour first gets mail.   These are Geometric distributed random variables.

So for the first $\checkmark$:
$$\mathsf P(X\geq k) = (1-p)^{k-1}\quad \text{for }k\in \{1,2...\}\\ \mathsf P(Y\geq k) = (1-w)^{k-1}\quad \text{for }k\in \{1,2...\}
\\ \mathsf P((X\vee Y)\geq k) = \mathsf P(X\geq k, Y\geq k) = (1-p)^{k-1}(1-w)^{k-1}
\\ \mathsf P((X\vee Y)\geq 8) = (1-p)^7(1-w)^7$$

---

The probability that the first mouldy mail arrives within a week will be, the probability that *any* mail which arrives that week will be mouldy: $$1-(1-pq)^7$$

For the second part, what you are looking for is the expected number of days until moldy mail arrives.   If $\mathsf E(Z)$ is the expected number of days until the next mouldy mail arrives, then by linearity of Expectation, the expected number of days until the *second* mouldy mail arrives is: $2\mathsf E(Z)$.   To find $\mathsf E(Z)$ we use the Law of Iterated Expectation, partitioning on whether the next mail is mouldy or not.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(Z) & = q \mathsf E(X) + (1-q)(\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(Z)) 
\\[2ex] \text{where}
\\[1ex] \mathsf E(X) & = 1/p & \text{is the expected days until the next mail arrives}
\\[3ex] \therefore 2\mathsf E(Z) & = ?
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Have just learned about the poisson process so I got messed up. 

for part (b), can you explain a bit more? Like the am I getting the probability of 1st received moldy mail will arrive within a week right? Not sure what Z stands for..

Comment: @Bubble: (b1) Consider that the complementary even is that no mouldy mail arrives on any of the seven days. (b2) Z is the number of days until the next mouldy mail: either the next mail is mouldy or its not any you have to check the next after that.  Then repeat to find the expected time until the second mouldy mail arrives.